# Excel telling me my name already exists when renaming a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, named-ranges

I have copied a table from an external workbook into a different workbook.  When I rename the table (on the design tab), Excel tells me that the name already exists.  When I rename a range within excel to the same name, this works fine.

The name does not appear in the name manager and this only occurs when I format the item as a table.

I have pasted the table as plain text and renamed and this works fine.  I then remove the name and convert to a table and rename and it once again tells me the name exists.
I'm completely baffled by this

As per comment - images below (sorry don't know if they can be added to comments):

Table in it’s location named as "BandLU2":

[image: Table in it’s location named as "BandLU2"]

Renamed to `BandLU`:

[image: Renamed to BandLU]

Check Name manager - name does not exist:
[image: Check Name manager - name does not exist]

Name a range with the same name and it works fine:
[image: Name a range with the same name and it works fine]

Comment: What happens if you try the same renaming in name manager? Can you post some screenshots?

Comment: Same issue if renamed in Name Manager - added images to original post (not sure if you can add them to comments!)

If I format the tabler as a range and name that BandLU it works fine - this is a workaround I've had to use for this but it removes the ability of making the list dynamic for lookups without VBA

Answer (score 7):

Someone pointed out on another forum that if any formula in a table refers to the name you want to use, Excel thinks for some reason that a table by that name already exists.

If this applies here, then you might fix it by removing or renaming all those existing references to the table name you want to use, name the table, and then replace the references.

Comment: That was exactly the issue I had. I removed the formula, tried again and it worked.